# Get DataItem when updating GridView

Tags: gridview, dataitem, onupdate

How can I get the underlying DataItem from a GridView row that is in edit mode and the user clicks on "Update"?

I have an editable GridView.  I've added a CustomValidator to the Edit view of one of the columns.  When the user clicks on Update I run a server validate method and need to get the underlying DataItem of the row being edited so that I can get the primary key of the data item for use in the validation.

```
GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].DataItem;
```

This does not work.  I guess because the GridView isn't databinded on the update command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.EditIndex].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I use the rowdatabound event instead of the update event of the gridview.

Here is an example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem%28VS.80%29.aspx#